# LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session bus: Failed to execute child process "dbus-launch" (No such file or directory) while x-forwarding

Tags: 16.04, server, x11-forwarding

I've set up **x-forwarding** on an **Ubuntu 16.04.3 server** and although the forwarding works, every time I start a GUI application it reports the following error in the terminal.

```
(<app-name>:<pid>) LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session bus: Failed to execute child process "dbus-launch" (No such file or directory)
```

This is obviously not critical, but it isn't working as it should.

How can I repair this?

**Edit** I'm mostly trying to start Firefox.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to install **'dbus-x11'**.

```
sudo apt-get install dbus-x11
```

I came to this solution by looking for similar issues.

I've found Pablo Saratxaga's answer on Serverfault, suggesting a script for a similar issue.

https://serverfault.com/a/673837/409813

I've thought it would be worth to run

> export $(dbus-launch)

because this is the main command that the script is starting.

The error message from the output is the following.

```
The program 'dbus-launch' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: 
apt install dbus-x11
```

I installed dbus-x11 and x-forwarding started to work without showing an error message.

Comment: dbus-x11 doesn't exist for ubunt 24.04.